# Android facebook auto status update

Tags: java, android, facebook

I have the facebook sample app posting test and picture updates separately to my wall. I want to combine these so that i can say something like 'Hey everybody, here is a picture of my dog! followed by the picture (dont care about layout really).

Any ideas if/how i do this?

Comment: Could you combine the two such that the "Hey everybody! ..."  is the caption to the picture, instead of a status on its own?

Comment: Yea, im not sure what is possible to do with pic - do they have status?

Comment: The closest you'll get is a caption on the picture, and it'll appear with the picture kind of like a status would. I suggest giving drarkayl's answer a shot, and replacing the `"caption"` field with the status you want to post.

Answer (score 0):

Make a bundle that and put all the information over there:

```
Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
        postParams.putString("name", "example");
        postParams.putString("caption", "caption of the image.");
        postParams.putString("description", "Put your status here.");
        postParams.putString("picture", "www.example.com/image.jpg");
```

Now use this bundle in the request object you make to post on timeline.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: i am supplying the pic myself - saved with my app and not in url. is this possible?

Comment: for doing it locally u can it this way 
Instead of putstring use putbytearray

image=getIntent().getExtras().getByteArray("data");

postParams.putByteArray("picture", image);